# Cisco VPN Packet Tracer

Tags: cisco, cisco-vpn

I'm not that good with VPN and cisco, and I wanted to create some VPN on Packet Tracert 5.3 
so I made some basic schema

Computer1
(IP:192.168.0.11)

ROUTER1
(IP:192.168.0.1)
(IP:10.0.0.1)

Router2
(IP:10.0.0.2)
(IP:192.168.2.1)

Computer2 
(IP:192.168.2.12)

connected like the following

Computer1--------Router1--------Router2--------Computer2

The following is the configuration for router1:

---

```
Building configuration...

Current configuration : 855 bytes
!
version 12.4
no service timestamps log datetime msec
no service timestamps debug datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname Gauche
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
crypto isakmp policy 1
 encr aes 256
 hash md5
 authentication pre-share
 lifetime 7200
!
crypto isakmp key cisco address 10.0.0.2
!
!
crypto ipsec transform-set Router1 esp-des esp-sha-hmac
!
crypto map Router1 1 ipsec-isakmp 
 set peer 10.0.0.2
 set transform-set Router1 
 match address 101
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
interface FastEthernet0/0
 ip address 192.168.0.1 255.255.255.0
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface FastEthernet0/1
 ip address 10.0.0.1 255.255.255.0
 duplex auto
 speed auto
 crypto map Router1
!
interface Vlan1
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
ip classless
!
!
access-list 101 permit ip 192.168.2.0 0.0.0.255 192.168.0.0 0.0.0.255
!
!
!
!
!
line con 0
line vty 0 4
 login
!
!
!
end
```

---

This is the configuration of router2:

---

```
Building configuration...

Current configuration : 890 bytes
!
version 12.4
no service timestamps log datetime msec
no service timestamps debug datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname Droite
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
crypto isakmp policy 1
 encr aes 256
 hash md5
 authentication pre-share
 lifetime 7200
!
crypto isakmp key cisco address 10.0.0.1
!
!
crypto ipsec transform-set Router1 esp-des esp-sha-hmac
!
crypto map Router1 1 ipsec-isakmp 
 set peer 10.0.0.1
 set transform-set Router1 
 match address 101
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
interface FastEthernet0/0
 ip address 10.0.0.2 255.255.255.0
 duplex auto
 speed auto
 crypto map Router1
!
interface FastEthernet0/1
 ip address 192.168.2.1 255.255.255.0
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface Vlan1
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
ip classless
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 10.0.0.1 
!
!
access-list 101 permit ip 192.168.0.0 0.0.0.255 192.168.2.0 0.0.0.255
!
!
!
!
!
line con 0
line vty 0 4
 login
!
!
!
end
```

---

But I really don't get why the VPN is not establishing, could some one help me, Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I checked your config but did not see your ACL configuration.You need to permit the interesting traffic then associate the crypto map to the access-list 101.
Hope this helps.

Comment: And then send it some interesting traffic too.. `ping ip 10.0.0.2 source 192.168.0.1` or similar.